# Плавный вывод текста на экран в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Всем доброго времени суток!

Недавно начал учить язык программирования Python и параллельно создаю текстовую игру на Pygame, поддерживать энтузиазм по этому для меня еще всё очень ново и это огромный мир. Научился создавать экран, выводить текст и т.д. Но выплёвывание текста на экран сразу, мне не нравится.

Отсюда вопрос: можно ли добиться плавного выведения текста на экран, как в квестах? Я знаю, что можно такого добиться в самом интерпретаторе Python, а вот можно ли это сделать на экране в Pygame, не нашел.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
font = pg.font.Font(None, 64)
y = 0

def poyav_text():
    global y
    txt_surf = font.render('transparent text', True, [255, 255, 255])
    alpha_img = pg.Surface(txt_surf.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)
    alpha_img.fill((255, 255, 255, y))
    txt_surf.blit(alpha_img, (0, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
    screen.blit(txt_surf, (30, 60))
    if y != 255:
        y = y + 1
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    poyav_text()
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```